Could I be blacklisted from applying to a company after submitting non-identical resumes?
Hello I think I messed up…
I applied to two different internships at the same company, but for each internship, I used a different email and resume.
The reason I did this was to make myself eligible for both internships as they required different sets of criteria to be eligible.
The only difference between the applications was the education section in my resume.
For one, I only listed my single degree and for the other I put down my actual double degree and a different degree start date + different expected graduation date. Home address was also different between the applications. The rest were the same.
But now I'm worried: could this get me blacklisted in the company if they find out its the same person altering their application?
I must admit, I was really desperate to get any sort of internship which led me to do this…
Is this situation bad enough for any company to put me on the blacklist?

im not asking the management choices of this company, i just want to know if this situation is bad enough for any company to put me on the blacklist -- i have edited my post to reflect this

(comments combined into an Answer.)

Are you talking about having a full resume and just removing parts for each application to tailor them to the position, or actual different resumes? Will one contradict the other for any specific date in the past?

yes there are contradicting dates, my first resume has a single degree under the education section and says: 2024 - 2027
my second one has my actual double degree and says 2022 - 2026

If you are asking about most sane management chains, the answer is no.
If your question is "should I worry", the answer is also clearly no.
If you insist on any, there must be at least one unreasonable company out there. But there's nothing you can do about it except, if asked about it, admit to it and give your reasons.
So worrying is still wasted effort. Have the explanation ready but odds are you will never be asked, and that if you are asked and give a reasonable answer they won't blackball you.
It may make them think about hiring someone else instead, if the comparison of two candidates is otherwise too close to decide. But again, there's nothing you can do about that now.
Realistically, resumes edited for the desired position are common these days. I don't think anyone would be shocked to find that applications for two different jobs looked different. If they disagree -- if it's clear you were lying -- then you'll probably just have both applications thrown in the recycling bin.  But that doesn't seem to be the case you are asking about.
